# Windows share indexing

Tags: windows, open-source, indexing, full-text-search

I'd like to index a Windows share for a workgroup of Win7 clients using open-source technologies. Users should be able to run full-text queries against the contents of .doc, .xls, .ppt, .pdf, .txt, .rtf, etc. files added through the UNC path via drag-n-drop, no need to manually trigger the index update. What's the software stack for this? Trying not to use Win Indexing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various open source tools for indexing documents, but they tend to require some tuning. I'd recommend you look at:

- [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)
- [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)
- [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)

Although Solr uses Java, it can [run on Windows](http://www.coldfury.us/index.php/2010/01/installing-and-running-solr-1-4-on-windows-tomcat/). In most cases you need to trigger the indexing process or schedule it. You might be able to use a [FilesystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) from .NET to trigger indexing of new files but it really depends on how soon they need to be visible in search results.